# How to set specific UNIQUE column in MySQL DML Statements

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

i'm facing an issue when i'm trying to insert records in a table with similar columns. So basically my table is structured like this ::

```
+-------+-------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| Field | Type        | Null | Key | Default | Extra          |
+-------+-------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| id    | int(11)     | NO   | PRI | NULL    | auto_increment |
| name  | varchar(50) | YES  | MUL | NULL    |                |
+-------+-------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
```

Now my PDO statement is this::

```
INSERT INTO supplement_brand (name) VALUES (:name)
```

So basically what i want is, that each name field will have a unique value. I already have INDEX set on the name field. Now i wanted to remove the primary key, and the auto-increment attributes from the id field. But that would entail bad database design practices.

Right now upon insertion the id field is being auto-incremented automatically, and many duplicate values are getting inserted in the name field:

Here is a sample of whats happening ::

```
+-----+-----------------------------+
| id  | name                        |
+-----+-----------------------------+
|   1 | 2 to 1 Protein Bar          |
|   7 | 2 to 1 Protein Bar          |
|   8 | 2 to 1 Protein Bar          |
|  28 | 2 to 1 Protein Bar          |
|  93 | 2 to 1 Protein Bar          |
|  98 | 2 to 1 Protein Bar          |
| 230 | 2 to 1 Protein Bar          |
| 231 | 2 to 1 Protein Bar          |
| 232 | 2 to 1 Protein Bar          |
|   2 | 360CUT                      |
|   3 | 360CUT                      |
|   4 | 360CUT                      |
|   5 | 360CUT                      |
|   6 | 360CUT                      |
|   9 | 4 Dimension Nutrition       |
|  10 | 4 Dimension Nutrition       |
|  11 | 4 Dimension Nutrition       |
|  12 | 4 Dimension Nutrition       |
|  13 | 4 Dimension Nutrition       |
|  14 | 4 Dimension Nutrition       |
|  15 | 4 Dimension Nutrition       |
|  16 | 4 Dimension Nutrition       |
|  17 | 4 Dimension Nutrition       |
|  18 | 4 Dimension Nutrition       |
|  19 | 4 Dimension Nutrition       |
|  20 | 4 Dimension Nutrition       |
|  21 | 4 Dimension Nutrition       |
|  22 | 4 Dimension Nutrition       |
|  23 | 4 Dimension Nutrition       |
|  24 | 4 Dimension Nutrition       |
|  25 | 4 Dimension Nutrition       |
+-----+-----------------------------+
```

How can i prevent the insertion of duplicate values in the name field. Please provide any sort of help, i'm literally stuck right now. Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
 ALTER TABLE  `supplement_brand` ADD UNIQUE (`name`);
```

This should ensure that the name field requires a unique value.

If you add another column ie brand and you want the name to be unique, but only if they share the same brand also you can do the following:

```
ALTER TABLE  `supplement_brand` ADD UNIQUE (`name` ,`brand`);
```

Comment: Yes this works right away. Thanks a lot for your answer. Its a life-saver. All hail Stack Overflow

Comment: Ok one more thing. Can i add this unique constraint to more than one column. So that when checking for duplicate key those two column will be checked together.

Answer (score 1):

`INDEX` will not guarantee uniqueness. There is `UNIQUE` key created for such tasks.

Comment: Can you please tell me how to add the unique constraint to more than one column so that when checking for duplicate value both of the field will be checked together.

Answer (score 0):

You have two option, first you can use UNIQUE for that field "name" statement above Or you can use UPSERT statements: follow this link for complete description: http://mechanics.flite.com/blog/2013/09/30/how-to-do-an-upsert-in-mysql/

Comment: It's still one option. In second case you have to create `UNIQUE` key to use `ON DUPLICATE KEY`.

Comment: you're right @ElonThan; I mean we can handle the duplicate error but just making the field unique or do update as the duplicate found